# Don't understand dynamic query results from Dapper within LinqPad

Tags: dapper, linqpad

I'm investigating using Dapper and tried this in LinqPad (you'll need to supply your own connection string and setup a 'Ticket' table to actually run this):

```
using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( builder.ToString() ) )
{
    conn.Open();
    var loadSql = 
        @"Insert into Ticket(StatusKey, Status, ContactFirstName, ContactPhoneNumber, WorkflowKey )
            Values ( @statusKey, @status, @first, @phoneNumber, @key )";
    var values = new[] 
    {
        new { statusKey = "O", status = "Open", first = "Bob", phoneNumber = "6855551425", key = "std" },
        new { statusKey = "R", status = "Researching", first = "Sue", phoneNumber = "77785552136", key = "exp" },
        new { statusKey = "OD", status = "Overdue", first = "Ted", phoneNumber = "6795551496", key = "std" },
        new { statusKey = "C", status = "Closed", first = "Mark", phoneNumber = "9945552678", key = "std" }
    };
    "Rows Added".Dump();
    conn.Execute( loadSql, values ).Dump();
    "".Dump();

    // Using <dynamic> returns same results
    var tickets = conn.Query("Select Status, ContactFirstName, ContactPhoneNumber From Ticket").ToList();
    "Tickets Found".Dump();
    tickets.Count().Dump();
    "".Dump();

    "Attempt to get first ticket".Dump();
    var firstTicket = tickets[0];
    firstTicket.Dump();
    (firstTicket ?? "first ticket is null").Dump();
    "--- End First Ticket Attempt ---".Dump();
    "".Dump();

    "Access items returned by query".Dump();
    tickets.ForEach( ticketObj => 
    {
            // ticketObj isn't null, but it not there either??
            "  Try to dump enumerated ticket".Dump();
            if(ticketObj == null) "    is null".Dump();
            ticketObj.Dump();
            //ticketObj.GetType().Dump(); // Null ref exception?
            "  --- End Enumeration Dump ---".Dump();

            // Have to cast to dictionary
            var ticket = (IDictionary<string,object>)ticketObj;
            string.Format("    {0}: {1} at {2}", ticket["Status"], ticket["ContactFirstName"], ticket["ContactPhoneNumber"]).Dump();

            "".Dump();
    });
    "--- End Access Test ---".Dump();
    "".Dump();


    conn.Execute("Truncate table ticket");
}
```

I got the following results:

```
Rows Added   
4

Tickets Found  
4

Attempt to get first ticket
--- End First Ticket Attempt ---

Access items returned by query
  Try to dump enumerated ticket
  --- End Enumeration Dump ---
    Open: Bob at 6855551425

  Try to dump enumerated ticket
  --- End Enumeration Dump ---
    Researching: Sue at 77785552136

  Try to dump enumerated ticket
  --- End Enumeration Dump ---
    Overdue: Ted at 6795551496

  Try to dump enumerated ticket
  --- End Enumeration Dump ---
    Closed: Mark at 9945552678

--- End Access Test ---
```

As you can see, following are weird:

- It lets me access the first item, but it won't dump and isn't null(??) and there are four items being returned.
- When I enumerate, if I cast to an IDictionary<string, object>, it works. But the actual item enumerated (ticketObj) is again not null, but I can't dump it. And if I try to get its type, I get a null reference exception.

The results are the same if I use the generic Query<dynamic> version as well.

I thought the dynamic results where supposed to be Expandos, and I could do something like

```
ticketObj.Status.Dump();
```

I.e. the fields from the query are turned into properties on the each object returned by Query.  What am I missing? How does this the dynamic feature of Dapper work?  Or maybe LinqPad does'nt work with dynamic objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first is that LINQPad dumps dynamic objects that implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` plainly as `IDictionary<string,object>` without first pivoting for a nicer view. This has been fixed for the next build.

The second issue is that calling `Dump()` directly on a `DapperRow` fails silently, instead of throwing the `RuntimeBinderException` one would expect ('DapperRow does not contain a definition for "Dump"'). This, I think, is a fault in the implementation of `DapperRow`.

There are a number of workarounds. The first, as you've discovered, is to cast first to `object`. Another workaround is to call the `Dump` extension method directly:

```
LINQPad.Extensions.Dump (ticketObj);
```

or:

```
LINQPad.Extensions.Dump (ticketObj, "First ticket");
```

Yet another workaround is to call `Console.WriteLine`, which LINQPad redirects to `Dump`:

```
Console.WriteLine (ticketObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've determined that this is a LinqPad issue.  Since it uses extension methods, it can't really handle dynamic types. However, if you cast the dynamic to an object, it works. So if you replace

```
firstTicket.Dump();
```

with

```
((object)firstTicket).Dump();
```

it works...sort of. It shows an IDictionary with the columns from the query. LinqPad has no way of knowing what the dynamically added columns are. [See SO this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14406826/99559) for more information.

This same technique also worked in the enumeration. If I change

```
ticketObj.Dump();
```

to

```
((object)ticketObj).Dump();
```

it works. I can also access dynamic properties, I just have to cast them first.

```
((string)ticketObj.Status).Dump();
```

The .GetType() doesn't appear to work with dynamic types...I don't think they have one. Note sure if this is correct, but this didn't work in a normal VS console app either.