# Newtonsoft Json deserialize to dynamic list with boolean property turns into string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Can't seem to deserialize a dynamic list that contains a boolean property back into a boolean.
I have the following json.

```
[
  {
    "Field1": 1,
    "Field2": "Test 1",
    "Field3": true
  },
  {
    "Field1": 2,
    "Field2": "Test 2",
    "Field3": false
  }  
]
```

When I use:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(jsonString)
```

I get Field3 = "True" or "False"
When binding to a grid or other control, it thinks this is a "string" and not a "boolean".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Chances are, the numbers are strings too, only you don't see that in your output. That would make sense that if you're not telling JSON.NET what the properties should be by not giving it a model, it will think you don't care.

Comment: I just ran a quick test with just the deserialization and I think the problem you are citing is with the binding step, not the deserialization step.  Capture the output from DeserializeObject and inspect it.  It is a Boolean type.  I think the value is being coerced into string later on.

Comment: You're probably right but when I bind it to a grid it thinks it is a string yet if I change <dynamic> to <ExpandoObject> it thinks it is a boolean. I'm 99.99% sure it is me doing something incorrect. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I tried to install LinqPad and figure out why it was working for [vendettamit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881798/vendettamit) yet it was not working in my C# application.
Which led me to this article on [How to Dump a Newtonsoft JObject in LinqPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406769/how-can-i-dump-a-newtonsoft-jobject-in-linqpad).

I then noticed that [rdavisau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752273/rdavisau) used the following code.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(jsonString)
```

Yet I was using the following code.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(jsonString)
```

So once I changed my code to the following. It all worked correctly.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExpandoObject>>(jsonString)
```

ExpandoObject was the piece I was missing.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I needed

Answer (score 3):

Since in JSON the value [`true` is bool and `"true"` is string](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm), it seems like a bug. I would create a new issue on their [issue tracker](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) for this.

A workaround would be to create a strong typed model for it.

```
public class FieldData
{
    public int Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
    public bool Field3 {get; set;}
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FieldData>>(jsonString);
```

This has also the advantage of compiletime check and better runtime performance.

Comment: I will look into the issue tracker. I do agree that strongly typed would be great but the json data is coming from a web service and is dynamic in nature.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried replicating your code as is in LINQPAD with `JSON.NET 9.0.1`. I didn't see the issue there:

[image]

Comment: I don't have LinqPad premium so I can't debug to see what you have listed above. But in my C# app using JSON.NET 9.0.1 this is not showing as a boolean. When I databind the output, it is only binding as a string.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran:

```
string s = "[{ \"Field1\": 1, \"Field2\": \"Test 1\", \"Field3\": true }, { \"Field1\": 2, \"Field2\": \"Test 2\", \"Field3\": false }   ]";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(s);
Console.WriteLine("Type: {0}", result[0].Field3.Type);
```

and it gave me:
Type: Boolean

The problem is likely because the JValue is being coerced into a string during the bind.